# Calling init Method in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, init

I'm just getting to the part of my Obj-C book where init methods are covered. I understand them, but I'm not sure where to call the method. I have a VC class that needs to have one of its `@property`s set to another value, besides the default 0 before the rest of the code is executed. VC is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Here is my code for the init method in VC.m:

```
- (id)initmethod
{
    if((self = [super init])){
        self.value = -1 ;
    }
    return self ;
}
```

Where do I call this? Do I need to have a sub class that calls it? Or do I need to manually create the VC object that is linked to the view and call this method there?

Comment: FYI - You better change that `if` to `if ((self = [super init])) {`. You do NOT want to do a comparison.

Comment: Change the name of your method to initMethod (with a capital M). Init methods have to start with the word "init", so I think the compiler isn't recognizing that when you have it all lowercase.

Comment: Call the thing `-init` unless you have a good reason not to. And *init family* probably means that you should use `-initMethod` instead of `-initmethod` (case is important here by convention).

Comment: Whenever an object is "created" by default it is supposed to be done with `myObject=[[MyObjectClass alloc]init]` or the equivalent shortcut `myObject=[MyObjectClass new]`. That is where your init method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to call this when you create the controller,

VC *vcInstance = [[VC alloc] initMethod];

There's really no need to create your own init method though, you can just override init.

If you're making your controller in a storyboard however, you would want to override initWithCoder, and set your value property there.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        _value = -1; // you should use the ivar rather than self.propertyName inside an init method
    }
    return self;
}
```

Likewise, if the controller is made in a xib file you should override initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: @jazpen, you put it in the subclassed controller's .m file. When you create a new UIViewController file, you get the boilerplate code for initWithNibName:bundle: automatically.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! It worked. Could you direct me to a page that would explain the `initWithNibName:bundle:` line well?

Comment: @jazpen, the description of the method is in the UIViewController Class Reference.